# Dell Perc 4/DC controller - managing it from Windows 7 on a not dell workstation?

Tags: windows-7, dell-perc

I've installed a Perc 4DC on a non dell workstation with windows 7. I have 
no issues with the drivers (used the 2003 ones), but I'm not sure what kind 
of disk management tool I could and should install.

By example, would Dell Array Manager am360a05 cause issues if installed on 
windows 7 x64 ? (given that such sw is for 2003 at most, and it replaces the windows disk management if I understood correctly)

Alessandro

Comment: This question is relevant to the users of this controller only. Wouldn't it make sense to check the manual and ask the manufacturer / seller support first (and summarize their input if you ask here nonetheless)?

Comment: This is really a question for Dell support ("Do you have a version of Dell Array Manager for Windows 7 x64 that supports this controller?"), not Server Fault...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're going to find a supported tool. That controller is *old* and certainly not intended for use in desktop operating system deployments, let alone one so much newer than the controller. I am familiar with the Array Manager software you're talking about and my gut says that it will work poorly, if at all, on a version of Windows that new.

I think you're best off using the BIOS management functionality or, better yet, just replacing the controller with something more modern.

Comment: I am actually using the bios due exactly to the gut feeling that that old Array Manager may cause issues due to the newer os.

Comment: Replacing it it's entirely a different issue... it's a gift I got, alongside a u320 300gb hd (and some smaller ones). I cannot use it with the hpux workstation I've here, due to lack of support.. and same is true for the alpha.. and since the xeon workstation I'm using has 2 legacy pci-x alongside the pci-e slots, I've added it to complement the onboard sas and exploit the 300gb disk

Answer (score 0):

There used to be a software package called OpenManage that Dell shipped with their PERC controllers. If it's still available, you may be able to get the remote management client installed on Win 7.

Comment: OpenManage might do it. You have to transform the MSI to get it to load on non-Server Windows versions, but otherwise it runs fine on Win7 (at least, modern versions of OM).